# Ironpython called through .NET not finding "math" library

Tags: python, .net

I'm using an IronPython script engine in my C# application.  It generally works ok, but for some reason it cannot find the "math" library (i.e. I can't "import math").  I checked my DLL's (IronPython.dll, Microsoft.Scripting, Microsoft.Dynamic) and they all seem to be ok and recent version (I copied them out of an IronPython 2.7.7.0 installation).  However, when I try to execute an "import math" command, it says "No module named math".  I can import "sys" and other modules ok, why not "math"?

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
            pyEngine = Python.CreateEngine();
            outputStream = new NotifyingMemoryStream();
            outputStream.TextWritten += OutputStream_TextWritten;
            outputStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream) { AutoFlush = true };
            pyEngine.Runtime.IO.SetOutput(outputStream, outputStreamWriter);
            pyEngine.Runtime.IO.SetErrorOutput(outputStream, outputStreamWriter);

            ScriptSource source = pyEngine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("import math" + Environment.NewLine + "math.log(10)", Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.AutoDetect);
            double b = source.Execute<double>()
```

The error occurs at the "double b = source..." line.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a file named `math.py` lying around that for some reason can't be imported (e.g., a syntax error)? (Of course that should really give you a better error message that tells you what's wrong with `math` rather than just saying there's no such module, but I wouldn't be _too_ surprised if it doesn't.)

Comment: Also, `sys` is special in that it's usually either built-in or frozen-in to the interpreter itself, while `math` is usually found in the standard library. So, maybe you just can't find your standard library. Do any other stdlib modules not work? Can you print out `sys.path` and `sys.metapath` and show us what they say?

Comment: Note that when I just run iron python as a stand-alone application, "import math" works fine.  My sys.path is below.  I don't seem to have sys.metapath defined.  They seem to just point to the C# program folder which doesn't have either "Lib" or DLLs" folder.  I tried modifying sys.path to the point to the "Lib" folder of the ironpython installation folder, but that didn't seem to help.  I don't actually see any "math.py" file in the ironpython folder, so am thinking that it must be internal since it works if I try to import it from ipy itself.

Comment: Please [edit] them into your answer; don't try to post them as comments.

Comment: sys.path: ['.', 'C:\\Users\\michaeld\\Documents\\MEMS_PROBE\\trunk\\Time Traveler\\TimeViewerWPF\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\michaeld\\Documents\\MEMS_PROBE\\trunk\\Time Traveler\\TimeViewerWPF\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\DLLs']

Comment: Anyway, I don't actually remember the recommended way to get `sys.path` setup when embedding IronPython, except that it's not the same as with CPython or Jython, but I suspect you're missing a step roughly equivalent to the CPython `Py_SetProgramName` (which is how you get it set up automatically, if you don't want to do it manually).

Comment: Also, I confirmed that I can't import any standard modules, not just "math".

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the IronPython DLLs out of an IronPython installation into your project does not get you the standard library.

The reason `sys` works is that it's one of a handful of special modules that are not just "builtins", but literally linked or frozen into the main interpreter. Most of the stdlib will not work.

---

The short version is: You have to either:

- Also copy the standard library, or
- Reference it in-place like this:

  ICollection searchPaths = pythonEngine.GetSearchPaths();
  searchPaths.add("D:\Absolute\Path\To\IronPython");
  pythonEngine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);

Obviously, the latter solution won't work if you want to deploy or distribute your app.

---

According to [this blog post](http://www.needfulsoftware.com/IronPython/IronPythonCS2) and a few others, it looks like the way most people handle this is to `NuGet` the stdlib into your project instead of copying stuff around manually. And, while you're at it, to `NuGet` IronPython instead of copying and pasting the DLLs.

This still doesn't completely solve deploy/distribute, but from there, it's just a matter of configuring your build to copy whichever parts of that `Lib` you want into your target, basically the same way you're presumably already doing with the DLLs. If you copy some or all of the stdlib libs into your build target, they'll automatically be on your search path; if you copy them into some custom subdirectory instead, you'll of course need to add that as shown above.

If you don't plan to deploy/distribute, you *still* may want to configure the copy. But, if not, you can just add `..\\..` to your search path.

(By the way, all of this is definitely not what I vaguely remember doing… but then what I remember is probably horribly out of date.)

Comment: Yes, that worked!  I did a NuGet to add the standard libraries to the project and now everything imports fine!  Thanks a lot for your help!